# Can i use two NICs to get double the bandwith to a switch?

Tags: networking, internet, internet-connection

I just switched to a 2.5 Gbps down / 1 Gbps up internet connection but my ISP gave me a router with only 1 Gbps ports, I have two network cards on my pc so I was wondering if I could maybe use them both together to use the full download bandwith. I have tried bonding them in the OS (balance-rr on ubuntu) but my speed went down to 100Mbps. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not really. However, before that: does your router's *WAN* connection even support 2.5 Gbps? Because if it doesn't …

Comment: The switch component of the router would have to support bonding. That doesn't mean you can't take advantage of 2Gbps of bandwidth by attaching both you computers NICs to the routers ports. But, you would only realize this when you are downloading multiple files simultaneously as the files could be transferred on different NICs each maxing out at 1Gbps. However, I not sure offhand whether this sharing of the bandwidth would happen by simply attaching the cables without addition configuration that are beyond my knowledge. I believe the topic is "networking balancing."

Comment: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/11271/how-to-setup-multiple-wans-with-load-balancing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11271/how-to-setup-multiple-wans-with-load-balancing)

Comment: “Is there a way to do this?” - Purchase a cheap 2.5GBs network card. If your router doesn’t even have a 2.5GBs network port there isn’t any way to achieve faster downloads an individual client machine faster than 1GBs.